# Jogo da forca python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ciência-da-computação

Galera, estou fazendo um jogo da forca no python. Minha duvida é a seguinte: como faço para ordernar os acertos de acordo com a palavra escolhida da forca e fazer ela duplicar a letra que digitei se houver mais de uma na palavra escolhida? obs: sem utilizar função

```
Nomes = ['EDWARD', 'MIDORYA', 'YUGI', 'SEIYA', 'ALLMIGHT']
Nome_Escolhido = []
Acertos = []
Digitadas = []
cont = 0
r = randint(0, 4)

Nome_Escolhido += Nomes[r]
q = ''
x = ' , '
print(q.join(Nome_Escolhido))  #teste

while True:
    Digitadas1 = input('\nDigite uma letra: ').capitalize()
    if Digitadas1 in Acertos:
        print('\nVocê já digitou esse número perdeu uma vida')
    elif Digitadas1 in Nome_Escolhido:
        Acertos.append(Digitadas1)
        print('\nAcertou')
    else:
        print('\nNão tem essa letra na palavra!')
        Digitadas.append(Digitadas1)
        cont += 1
    if Nome_Escolhido == Acertos:
        print(f'\nVocê ganhou!\n Nome:{q.join(Nome_Escolhido)} ')
        break
    if cont == 3:
        print('\nVocê errou 3 vezes então perdeu o jogo')
        break
    print(f'Letras usadas {x.join(Digitadas)}') #teste
    print(f'Erros: {cont}')  #teste
    print(q.join(Acertos)) #teste
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode na lista Acertos, inserir algo para preenche-la, como 0 até se atingir a quantidade len(Nome_Escolhido). Utilizando Edward como exemplo que possui 6 letras:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], logo você pode utilizar um for para percorrer a palavra e acrescentar na posição de Acertos:

```py
for i in range(len(Nome_Escolhido)):
   if Digitadas1 == Nome_Escolhido[i]:
      Acertos[i] = Digitadas1
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo, muito obrigado!